# Rails 4.2: Active Job After Redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-activejob

This is my first time using **ActiveJob** so I'm still wrapping my head around the details. I have a form that when saved via an `Execute` button, it performs some API calls that take a very long time.

I would like the page to redirect to the index without the long wait. Here is my controller's create action..

**campaigns_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)

    if @campaign.save

        flash[:success] = "Campaign Successfully Saved!"
        redirect_to campaigns_path

        if params[:save_type] == 'Execute'
            FolderPushJob.perform_later(@campaign)
        end

    else
        flash[:error] = "There was a problem launching your Campaign."
        redirect_to new_campaign_path
    end
  end
```

...and my Job in it's infant stage

**folder_push_job.rb**

```
class FolderPushJob < ActiveJob::Base
    queue_as :default

      def perform(campaign)
        ...some api calls..
      end
```

What would be the best way to make this work?

**UPDATE**

One issue I found is that I did not have a backend for the Job, so I installed the `delayed_job` gem.

**config/application.rb**

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

Now it redirects and doesn't run the Job at all.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under the impression that I could create a delayed job set to run at a certain time and while developing, watch it run. It appears that while in development mode, I have to start the jobs manually. According to this blog..

[Simple Steps to Implement Delayed Job in Rails](http://blog.andolasoft.com/2013/04/4-simple-steps-to-implement-delayed-job-in-rails.html#)

> Start up the jobs process There are two ways to do this.
>
> If application is in development mode, we would use the below rake
>   task instead.
>
> ```
> rake jobs:work
> ```
>
> If application is in production mode, then it is preferred to use the
>   “delayed_job” script.

I also learned that this `rake` task can be ran alongside the server. Keep it running and it will perform the jobs as you interact with your app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform the job before the redirect_to because your way rails execute the redirect and never call the Job

Comment: The order of the redirect_to didn't make a difference, still getting the same outcome. The Job exists regardless, it just doesn't run.